# What's the output during PyPy build means?

Tags: pypy

During the building phase of `PyPy`, the script produces some nice ASCII characters that looks really interesting. What does each character represent? How to interpret this output? What really is PyPy build doing while producing this ASCII art?

[image: output from PyPy build]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [mandelbrot set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set).

> Enjoy Mandelbrot :-)

according to http://pypy.org/download.html . This creates an enjoyable build experience.

Comment: What? So it means nothing to the build itself?

Comment: It seems like the authors just decide to show some interesting ASCII art during the boring build :-( http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-pypy-draw-a-mandelbrot-fractal-while-translating

Comment: it's a progress bar. pure dot based progress bar is quite boring. enjoy :) it does not slow anything down.